# Issue while deleting any record in Jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

```
deleteAction: url + "?Id=" + $("#ddl").val()
```

Caching `deleteUrl` so Id is not getting updated after I change the value from the dropdown (ddl).

Any solution ?

Comment: Not sure what the question being asked is here; maybe add a little more background and detail?

Answer (score 0):

Append a parameter on to your delete URL for cache-busting

```
deleteAction: url + "?Id=" + $("#ddl").val() + "&nocache=" + (new Date()).getTime()
```

The term is cache busting.

By the way, if you have the same ID being reused, you might want to have a look at your backend design. It's not usually done.